# Possible to configure OS X VPN to split traffic between VPN and local interface?

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, vpn

I'm using the built-in OS X VPN tool to connect to my company's network.  I notice that, when I'm connected, all traffic goes over the VPN.

In the past when I've used the Windows VPN tool I was able to configure it such that only traffic to certain IP ranges and/or host names went over the VPN and everything else went over the local network.

Is that possible with a default OS X VPN?  I don't see anything in the settings...

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. First, you have to remove the checkmark from "Send all traffic over VPN connection" in Settings -> Network -> Your VPN -> Advanced.

Then, from the Terminal you can use "route" to add specific hosts that should be routed via your VPN.

```shell
sudo /sbin/route add -host pandora.com -interface ppp0
```

In this example, "pandora.com" is the host that should be routed via the VPN and `ppp0` is the name of the VPN network interface (`ifconfig` shows you the list of network interfaces).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at the man page for 'route'.  I'm assuming it will let me add IP ranges as well.

Comment: will I still be able to connect to the routed website if I am now directly connect to my company's network and the VPN is off?

Comment: Where exactly is "Send all traffic over VPN connection" option? I can't find it in Settings/Network/My VPN/Advanced

Comment: This didn't work for me, it may have changed on the most recent OS

Answer (score 4):

To make it work also with the Pandora app, you can use

```
sudo /sbin/route add -host internal-tuner.pandora.com -interface ppp0
```

and when you finish, you can simply do

```
sudo /sbin/route delete -host internal-tuner.pandora.com -interface ppp0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation enough to comment on kiteloop's answer (score 28 as of today) or opoloko's answer (score 2 as of today). I was facing the same problem (listening to Pandora on OS X, 10.6.8) and am now listening to Pandora via the Pandora app (which has better sound quality I believe than via browser and certainly uses less CPU (about 3% in activity monitor).

The comment from Maskime to schlingel.me does not lead to a detailed post about Pandora's IP addresses but rather to a photography weblog which does not include that post. Neither does Googling "schlingel + pandora" bring up a current location. It's a dead end.

On the other hand, Opoloko's suggestion for the Pandora app works brilliantly.

1. Download and install the Pandora OS X app.
2. Just turn off the checkmark from "Send all traffic over VPN connection" in Settings -> Network -> Your VPN -> Advanced.
3. Apply changes.
4. Connect your VPN.
5. Open terminal.
6. Run `ifconfig`.
7. Look for `ppp` to discover the exact location of the VPN interface whatever the ppp address is.
8. Include that string in opoloko's command: `sudo /sbin/route add -host internal-tuner.pandora.com -interface ppp0`

Additional Notes: In this case you don't need to cover a range of Pandora IP's just the internal-tuner.pandora.com address. All CDN/etc servers don't need to be covered either just the initial internal-tuner.pandora.com. While I thought one could replace `internal-tuner.pandora.com` with `pandora.com` this won't work. Neither will a simple wildcard like `*.pandora.com` work in route. It returns a bad address warning.

To turn off the Pandora VPN, use opoloko's command with the correct ppp interface number:

```
sudo /sbin/route delete -host internal-tuner.pandora.com -interface ppp0
```

Happy listening. Huge thanks to opoloko who offered a simple and usable solution to what is a keen issue for music lovers since Last.FM radio went down. Pandora is the only really good suggestion algorithm left standing and which introduces a listener to new music.